# Django ranking solution

Tags: django, ranking, rownum

I'm trying to build a simple ranking system where I order subjects by 'Score' and then by 'ID'.
I originally built this is PHP by setting a 'rownum' variable in SQL and calling that 'Rank' like this:

```
public function rank() {
    global $database;
    $sql = "SET @rownum :=0";
    $database->query($sql);
    $sql = "SELECT rank FROM ( 
        SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rank, id, score 
        FROM subjects
        ORDER BY score DESC, id ASC) AS derived_table 
        WHERE id = {$this->id}";

    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $row = $database->fetch_array($result_set);
    return array_shift($row);
    }
```

I could possibly index it from a Queryset but I haven't figured out how to do that either.
Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this in Django?

the Model:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you built out your Django Model yet for your database? If so could you include? This would normally be  method in your django model.py

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
order_by('score', 'pk') #pk is the ID or primary key
```

Check out [Django Book: Chapter 5 Models](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/)

Comment: So if I need to find the position of a subject in that list is there a better way than interating through the queryset? Could I say 'find ID 4' and it would spit back '22'?

Answer (score 0):

With the [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method this can be done.

```
Blog.objects.extra(
    select={
        'entry_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog_entry WHERE blog_entry.blog_id = blog_blog.id'
    },
)
```

Comment: I'm looking for it to be sorted by two parameters, then to find out the index of where ever the subject ends up (by id)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
someSubject = Subject.objects.get(name='someSubject')
someSubject_rank = Subject.objects.filter(score__gt=someSubject.score).count()+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the data and not process the rank field of each row in any way further, there's the simple and thus elegant way of using Django's [`forloop.counter` template variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
# your views.py    
return (super(View, self).get_context_data(
        subjects=Subject.objects.order_by("-score", "pk"), 
        **kwargs)
)

# your template.html
{% for subject in subjects %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ subject.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ subject.score }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```